# Django Rest Framework serilize relations

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to serialize a fields in related models.

I got a models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Order ID', unique=True)
    order_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Order name', max_length=255)
    order_type = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Campaign type')

class Types(models.Model):
    delimiter = models.CharField(verbose_name='Delimiter', max_length=255)
    status = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Status', default=True)
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Title', max_length=255)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='User name', max_length=200, unique=True)

class Report(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, to_field='order_id', verbose_name='Order ID')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='User ID')
    ad_type = models.ForeignKey(Types, verbose_name='Type')
    imp = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Total imp')
    month = models.DateField(verbose_name='Month', default=datetime.datetime.today)
```

View:

```
class ReportLisAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ReportSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        month = parse_date(self.kwargs['month']) - relativedelta(day=1)

        queryset = (
            Report.objects.filter(month=month)
            .values_list(
                'user', 'user__name', 'order__order_id',
                'order__order_name', 'order__order_type'
            ).all().annotate(Sum('imp'))
        )
        return queryset
```

Serializer:

```
class ReportSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Report
        depth = 1
```

I need to get all field like in 'queryset' in get_queryset()
but I got an error:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `imp` on
>   serializer `ReportSerializer`. The serializer field might be named
>   incorrectly and not match any   attribute or key on the `tuple`
>   instance. Original exception text was: 'tuple' object has no attribute
>   'imp'.

But if I return in get_queryset() just Report.objects.filter(month=month).all() I'll get all objects and related object with all field, without aggregate of imp and not grouping.

So the question is how to make serializer return structure that set in queryset?

Answer (score 1):

The `get_queryset` method requires to return a queryset but you are returning a tuple beacause of [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values-list). Either drop it to return a queryset or go with a more generic view like `APIView`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way how to do it.

As I use .values_list() it return list object instead of queryset object. So for serializer do understand what is inside the list I defined all fields in serializer. And in to_representation() I return dictionary like it should be.

Serializer:

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.IntegerField()
    user_name = serializers.CharField()
    order_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    order_name = serializers.CharField()
    order_type = serializers.IntegerField()
    imp = serializers.IntegerField()

class Meta:
    model = Report
    fields = [
        'user', 'user_name', 'order_id', 'order_name',
        'order_type', 'imp'
    ]
    depth = 1

def to_representation(self, instance):
    Reports = namedtuple('Reports', [
        'user',
        'user_name',
        'order_id',
        'order_name',
        'order_type',
        'imp',
    ])
    return super(ReportSerializer, self).to_representation(
        Reports(*instance)._asdict()
    )
```

View:

```
class ReportLisAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ReportSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        month = parse_date(self.kwargs['month']) - relativedelta(day=1)

        queryset = (
            Report.objects.filter(month=month)
            .values_list(
                'user', 'user__name', 'order__order_id',
                'order__order_name', 'order__order_type'
            ).all().annotate(Sum('imp'))
        )
        return queryset

    def list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
        # actualy that's it! part of which is below can be pass and just
        # return Response(serializer.data)

        result = {
            'month': parse_date(self.kwargs['month']).strftime('%Y-%m'),
            'reports': []
        }

        inflcr = {}
        for item in serializer.data:
            inflcr.setdefault(item['user'], {
                'id': item['user'],
                'name': item['user_name'],
                'campaigns': []
            })

            orders = {
                'id': item['order_id'],
                'name': item['order_name'],
                'type': item['order_type'],
                'impressions': item['imp'],
            }

            inflcr[item['user']]['campaigns'].append(orders)
        result['reports'] = inflcr.values()

    return Response(result)
```

Comment: Sorry. I added description to my answer.